# First image is not loading on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple quiz app. I am using JQuery, but my first question is no loading on page load. But if I click clear(reset) button, then it loading page fine.

```
//On Submit Button
  $("button#answer").on("click",function(){
    checkAnswer();
    questionNumber++;

    if(questionNumber === questions.length){
      $(this).css("display","none");
      $("#clear").css("display","block");
    }
    else {
      nextQuestion();
    };
  });
```

Full working code is here in this JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dQgbs/

I don't have my images loaded to fiddle, but as you will see when you run it you only see buttons, but when you hit answers button, you get second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try calling `nextQuestion();` in document ready

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dQgbs/1/)

Answer (score 2):

hey i made some changes in code like.

In html code i added one button--Start

```
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <div class="nav-hold"> <a href="#" class="nav-logo">Qu<span id="blink">:</span>z Time - Guess this person</a>
 <a href="#" class="nav-status" id="quiz_status"></a>

    </div>
</nav>
<div class="wrap_container">
    <div class="firstContainer">
        <img id="question_image" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="secondContainer">
        <div class="answers"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <button id="answer">Answer</button>
        <button id="start">Start</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In css--

```
#start{
    margin-left:50%;
    }
```

In script--

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button#answer").css("display", "none");
    $("button#clear").css("display","none");
    //Global Variables

    var questionNumber = 0,
        correctAnswers = 0,
        counter = 0,
        userAnswers = new Array(),

        questions = [{

            question: "Images/img1.jpg",
            choices: ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5"],
            quesNum: 1,
            correctAns: 0
        },

        {
            question: "Images/img2.jpg",
            choices: ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5"],
            quesNum: 2,
            correctAns: 1
        },

        {
            question: "Images/img3.jpg",
            choices: ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5"],
            quesNum: 3,
            correctAns: 3
        },

        {
            question: "Images/img4.jpg",
            choices: ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5"],
            quesNum: 4,
            correctAns: 2
        },

        {
            question: "Images/img5.jpg",
            choices: ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5"],
            quesNum: 5,
            correctAns: 4
        }];

    //Question Number
    $("#quiz_status").text("Question " + questions[0].quesNum + " of " + questions.length);


/**********my code**************/

$("button#start").on("click", function(){

    $("button#answer").css("display","block");
    $("button#clear").css("display","block");
    $("button#start").css("display","none");
     checkAnswer();
     if (questionNumber === questions.length) {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $("#clear").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            nextQuestion();
        };

    });
/**********my code**************/
    //On Submit Button
    $("button#answer").on("click", function () {
                    alert("second");
        checkAnswer();

         questionNumber++;
        if (questionNumber === questions.length) {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $("#clear").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            nextQuestion();
        };

    });

    //On Clear Quiz Button
    $("button#clear").on("click", function () {
        restart();
        nextQuestion();
    });

    //Move to next question - update question & answers
    function nextQuestion() {
        $("#quiz_status").text("Question " + questions[questionNumber].quesNum + " of " + questions.length);
        $("#question_image").attr({
            src: questions[questionNumber].question,
            alt: 'Picture'
        }).height(200).width(200);

        var multChoice = $.each(questions[questionNumber].choices, function (index, value) {
            value
        });
        $("div.answers label").remove();
        $.each(multChoice, function (index, value) {
            $("div.answers").append("<label class='radio'><input type='radio' name='check' data-ans=" + index + ">" + value + "</label>");
        });
    }

    //Check user answer against correct answer - store user answer & keep count for right or wrong answers
    function checkAnswer() {

        var userAns = $("input[type=radio]:checked").data("ans");

        userAnswers.push(userAns);

        if (userAns === questions[counter].correctAns) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    $(correctAnswers).appendTo('quiz_status');

    //Restart Quiz
    function restart() {
        questionNumber = 0;
        correctAnswers = 0;
        counter = 0;
        userAnswers = new Array();
        $("#answer").css("display", "block");
        $("#clear").css("display", "none");
    }

    // Function to create a BLINK TEXT effect
    function blink(selector) {
        $(selector).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 50, "linear", function () {
            $(this).delay(800);
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 50, function () {
                blink(this);
            });
            $(this).delay(800);
        });
    }
    blink("a #blink"); //Call blink text function

});
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dQgbs/5/)

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, This is a great input, I might like to add that start button because it gives you an entry point.